# R - Create df columns based on sum of values in row

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, transpose

Say I have this df:

[image: original df]

What I'd like to do is create columns that correspond to the month, where the value for the new column is the sum of the values for that person from the "Total" column. So the output would be this:

[image: summarised df]

How could I accomplish this in R? Was considering using the mutate() function or possibly:

```
for(i in 1:6){

nums <- df[which(df$Month == i),]
for(person in nums$Person){
per <- nums[which(nums$Person == person),]
df[[paste0('Month ', i)]] <- sum(per$Total)

}
}
colnames(df) <- c('Person', 'Year', 'Month', 1, 2,3,4,5,6)
```

But I feel like there's a much better way to do this.